# jQuery DataTables column sorting on other column

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, datatable

My jQuery Datatable is not sorting properly in some columns. When I sort the GGC_ID column, it's sorting properly, but when I sort the CustomerID column, its not sorting. And when I sort the Customer Name column, the CustomerID column is the one that is sorting.

Here's my code:

### record.js:

```
var tbl = $('#tbl').DataTable({
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "order": [],
    "searchable": true,
    "columnDefs": [
     { 
          "orderable": false, 
          "targets": [0,4] 
     }
     ],
     "ajax": {
                url: "fetch.php",
                method: "POST"
            }
     });
```

fetch.php

```
     $query = '';
    $query .= "SELECT records.GGC_ID, company.Comp_Name, customer.CUST_ID, customer.CUST_NAME FROM records INNER JOIN company on company.Comp_ID = records.COMP_ID INNER JOIN customer ON customer.CUST_ID = records.CUST_ID ";

    if(isset($_POST["search"]["value"])) 
    {
        $query .= 'WHERE Comp_Name LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" ';
        $query .=  'OR CUST_NAME LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" ';
        $query .=  'OR GGC_ID LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" ';
    }

    if(isset($_POST["order"])) {
        $query .= 'ORDER BY '.$_POST['order']['0']['column'].' '.$_POST['order']['0']['dir'].
        ' ';
    } else {
        $query .= "ORDER BY GGC_ID DESC ";
    }

    if($_POST["length"] != -1) {
        $query .= 'LIMIT ' . $_POST['start'] . ', ' . $_POST['length'];
    }

    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute();

    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();

    $data = array();

    $filtered_rows = $stmt->rowCount();

    foreach ($result as $row) {

        $sub_array = array();
        $sub_array[] = $row["Comp_Name"];
        $sub_array[] = $row["GGC_ID"];
        $sub_array[] = $row["CUST_ID"];
        $sub_array[] = $row["CUST_NAME"];
        $sub_array[] = '<button type="button" name="update" id="'.$row["CUST_ID"].'" 
                        class = "btn btn-default details" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#customer_modal">Details</button> ';
        $data[] = $sub_array;

    }
    $output = array(
        "draw"              => intval($_POST["draw"]),
        "recordsTotal"      => $filtered_rows,
        "recordsFiltered"   => get_total_all_records(),
        "data"              => $data  
    );
    echo json_encode($output);
```

Comment: Check if `$_POST['order']['0']['column']` and `$_POST['order']['0']['dir']` receives the right value in it.

Comment: How do I check that? Im new in DataTables. When i echo the $_POST, error is occuring. :(.

Comment: try print_r($_POST);die;

Comment: It prints like these when I sort the Customer Name Column, and prints the $_POST['order'].
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [column] => 2
            [dir] => asc
        )
)
I think the $_POST variables are receiving the right value. But I dont know why some columns are not sorting properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$_REQUEST["order"][0][column]  - does not have field name, it has index of field in columns

```
$index = $_REQUEST["order"][0][column];
ORDER BY $_REQUEST["columns"][ $index ]["name"]
```

You can open google console, network tab, find server request - header tab to see variables it sends.

Also

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_REQUEST); 
echo "</pre>";
exit();
```

Your fixed code:

```
$index = $_POST['order']['0']['column'];
$field = $_POST["columns"][ $index ]["name"];
$query .= 'ORDER BY '.$field.' '.$_POST['order']['0']['dir'].
        ' ';
```

Comment: I think this is the right code, ill try this. But I have already solve it through if else statement for which i compare the value of $_POST['order']['0']['column'] to the column number in my db, depending on the value for my order by statement.

Answer (score -1):

When you sort the Customer Name column, `echo $query`, check sql is right.